# Update database issue

Tags: database, drush, upgrading

In 2 of my 3 Drupal websites, `drush updb` crashes with the following error after upgrading from Drupal 9.5.11 to Drupal 10.2.2.

```
In BatchStorage.php line 143:
  [Exception]
  Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed
Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Batch/BatchStorage.php:143
 serialize() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Batch/BatchStorage.php:143
 Drupal\Core\Batch\BatchStorage->create() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Batch/BatchStorage.php:107
 Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Batch\BatchStorage->create() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/batch.inc:146
 _drush_backend_batch_process() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/includes/batch.inc:55
 drush_backend_batch_process() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/UpdateDBCommands.php:410
 Drush\Commands\core\UpdateDBCommands->updateBatch() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/UpdateDBCommands.php:73
 Drush\Commands\core\UpdateDBCommands->updatedb() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:276
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:212
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php:176
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php:391
 Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:326
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1096
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:324
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:175
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:110
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:40
 Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:139
 require() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/drush/drush/drush:4
 include() at /var/www/html/drupal/web/vendor/bin/drush:120
``

Website is not down and I can access the back-end, but it can't stay like this.

I followed [How to upgrade from Drupal 9 to Drupal 10][1].

Do you have any idea?

I'll try to spot differences with my 3rd website which has well supported the upgrade.
















  [1]: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/how-to-upgrade-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10
```

Comment: What version of drush are you using?  Try temporarily removing drush with composer.

Comment: Yeah the error says something with Drush. Drush version and PHP version would be first thing to check.

Comment: Using Drush 12.4.3.0, PHP 8.1.13

Comment: Could be your composer is too old. Try `composer self-update`  and then `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 2):

As @4uk4 points out, this issue happened to me because of an old composer. Updating composer to its latest version and dumping autoload worked for me:

```
composer.phar self-update
composer.phar dump-autoload
```

After that, I could update the DB with no further issues:

```
/vendor/bin/drush updb --verbose
```

I got this from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3098942#comment-15378094